# Problemas al trabajar con fechas en MongoDB y NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

estoy trabajando con mongodb y node tratando de traer datos que se encuentran entre dos fechas, pero la consulta no me devuelve nada, obviamente estos datos estan.

campos MongoDB

```
{  
  otros datos
    "usuario" : ObjectId("5cb4d3b35ef22e1e9815d522"),
    "created" : ISODate("2019-05-16T17:15:05.617Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Codigo Node

```
ordenRoutes.get('/buscar',   (req: any, res: Response) =>{
const ini = req.body.inicio
const fn = req.body.fin

const ordenes =  Orden.find({created:{ $gte: new Date(ini).toISOString(),
                                       $lt: new Date(fn).toISOString()
                                      }}).exec().then( resp => {
                                      console.log(resp);                        
                                      }); 
 res.json({
        ok: true,
        ordenes
    });
});
```

Estoy probando este codigo en postman, que estare haciendo mal, llevo varios dias tratando de solucionarlo. Gracias

Comment: creo que tu primer problema viene en que estás creando mas las fechas, ya que deberia ir `$gte: new Date(ini).toISOString()` y `$lt: new Date(fn).toISOString()` sin las comillas

Comment: Hola, fue un error de tipeo, pero originalmente estaban sin comillas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes al menos 3 errores en la forma en la que estás consultando los datos.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea consultar una colección de documentos en MongoDB, filtrando por rango de fechas. El campo sobre el cual se hará la consulta es de tipo `Date` (en el Shell de Mongo se define como `ISODate`).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Como dije al principio tienes al menos 3 errores, y además, voy a asumir que los valores que envías en el cuerpo de tu solicitud son valores de fecha válidos.

El primer error está en que `new Date(ini).toISOString()` devuelve un tipo `string`, y por lo tanto la consulta no devolverá resultados ya que el valor que debe compararse es de tipo `Date`. Lo mismo sucede con `new Date(fn).toISOString()`.

Ejemplo:

```js
let inicioString = new Date(Date.now()).toISOString();
let inicioDate = new Date(Date.now());
console.log('inicioString es Date: ', inicioString instanceof Date && !isNaN(inicioString.valueOf()));
console.log('inicioDate es Date: ', inicioDate instanceof Date && !isNaN(inicioDate.valueOf()));
```

Lo más saludable es crear las variables tipo `Date` y pasarlas luego como referencia a la consulta. Una forma en la que puedes hacer esto es la siguiente:

```
const inicio = new Date(req.body.inicio);
const fin = new Date(req.body.fin);
```

Con esto ya tenemos las variables tipo `Date` que podremos pasar a la consulta de mongo:

```
Orden.find({created: {$gte: inicio, $lt: fin}})
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
    return res.status(200).json({
      ok: true,
      resp
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      error
    });
  });
```

El segundo error, es que realizas una petición `GET` en la que estás pasando parámetros en el cuerpo (`body`) de la solicitud. No se exactamente cómo realizas la petición desde el lado cliente, pero lo recomendado es usar los métodos `http` según la especificación. Así, el método idóneo para enviar datos al servidor desde el lado cliente es el método `POST`

El último error que mencionaré es que estás asignando a la variable `ordenes` el resultado del método `find()` de tu modelo. Dicho método es asíncrono, por lo tanto mientras el mismo se ejecuta, JavaScript continuará ejecutando la siguiente línea de código: `res.json({ok: true, ordenes})`, dando como resultado que `ordenes` sea de tipo `undefined` ya que el método `find()` aún está procesando la información.

Para resolver esto tienes algunas opciones:

1. **Usar `async/await`:**

Para usar funciones `async` solo debemos anteponer la palabra clave `async` a nuestra función y cuando necesitamos realizar un proceso asíncrono (como `find`) anteponemos la palabra `await`. De esta forma Javascript interpeta que el método que hemos llamado con `await` es un método asíncrono y esperará que el mismo devuelva un resultado.

Dado que el método `find` es asíncrono, debemos envolver nuestro código en un bloque `try catch`, ya que si la llamada al método causa un error y no lo controlamos el mismo podría detener la ejecución de nuestra aplicación.

Dicho esto, una forma de implementar `async/await` sería:

```
// usaremos el método POST
ordenRoutes.post('/buscar', async (req: any, res: Response) => {
    const inicio = new Date(req.body.inicio);
    const fin = new Date(req.body.fin);
    const query = { // <- construimos nuestro documento query
      created: {
        $gte: inicio,
        $lt: fin
      }
    };
    // usamos try catch para ejecutar la consulta
    try {
      const ordenes = await Orden.find(query).exec(); // usamos await
      return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        ordenes
      });
    } catch(error) {
      // en caso de error en la consulta mostramos el error
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).json({
        ok: false,
        error
      });
    }
});
```

Con esto ya debemos tener resultados de nuestra consulta

2. **Usar `then()` y `catch()`:**

Según la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises) de Mongoose (asumo que usas Mongoose), las queries no son Promesas, pero tienen métodos `then()` y `catch()` que pueden ser usados. En este caso no hace falta declarar la función tipo `async`. Además, el resultado de la consulta será manejado dentro del método `then()`. En caso de error, el mismo será manejado dentro del método `catch()`. Una forma de implementarlo sería:

```
ordenRoutes.post('/buscar', (req: any, res: Response) => {
    const inicio = new Date(req.body.inicio);
    const fin = new Date(req.body.fin);
    const query = { // <- construimos nuestro documento query
      created: {
        $gte: inicio,
        $lt: fin
      }
    };
    // hacemos el llamado directamente al metodo find()
    Orden.find(query)
      .then((ordenes) => {  // usamos then() y pasamos una función que se ejecutará al momento que find devuelva un resultado
        return res.status(200).json({
          ok: true,
          ordenes
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => { // capturamos errores
        // en caso de error en la consulta mostramos el error
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({
          ok: false,
          error
        });
      });
});
```

3. **Usar una función `callback`**

Tal como lo indica la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) de Mongoose, puedes pasar una función `callback` al método `find`, así puedes ejecutar el método y procesar los resultados dentro de la función. Una forma de hacerlo sería:

```
ordenRoutes.post('/buscar', (req: any, res: Response) => {
    const inicio = new Date(req.body.inicio);
    const fin = new Date(req.body.fin);
    const query = { // <- construimos nuestro documento query
      created: {
        $gte: inicio,
        $lt: fin
      }
    };
    // hacemos el llamado directamente al metodo find() y le pasamos una función callback
    Orden.find(query, (error, ordenes) => {
      if(error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({
          ok: false,
          error
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        ordenes
      });
    });
});
```

Con esto ya deberías poder realizar tu consulta sin problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la catreda, me quedo claro gracias por tu tiempo